# Searching for image Firebase using ML Kit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-vision, firebase-mlkit

I have a set of a hundred or so images (eventually this will be a few thousand). From my app I want to be able to take a picture and upload it to Firebase and search wether the picture contains one of the images from the set and if so which one. Does ML Kit provide a suitable way to do this? I also saw that there is now a Google Cloud Vision API but this might be overkill? Is there already some open source projects on something similar?

Comment: For a list of the supported models in ML Kit, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/. ML Kit currently doesn't support classifying images by similarity. Recommending alternatives is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but typically a Google search is your friend for finding such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can now create custom image classification models from your own training data using ML Kit. Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/automl-vision-edge